# Is there a way to overwrite the refresh button action?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, cross-browser, reload

I would like to use some kind of `preventDefault` function to overwrite what hitting the refresh button on the browser does (or also pressing `CTRL/CMD+R`).

Is there something that allows me to prevent refreshing the page?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything in Firefox.

```
window.onunload = function(){
     alert("unload event detected!");
}
```

Comment: maybe `window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function(){`

Comment: this kind of works ... thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use `onbeforeunload` to prompt whether they'd like to leave:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you really sure?\nI don't know why anyone would want to leave my beautiful website!";
};
```

However, you can't override it any more than that.

Comment: As per my experience... There's no solution for this in javascript... though it exists it will not work for all browsers... i have implemented this at the server by readin and writing the cookie values from client...

Comment: rightly so, imagine the kind of havoc that could be caused if default browser behavior could be overridden like this!

Comment: it would be highly useful though for things like refreshing the comment feed to a video without resetting the playback, or similar.