# stop user from resubmitting a form / aka stop from refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop user from refreshing a page that contains form. Basically, I want to stop user from pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Lets say I have the following

```
<form action="#">
<input type="text"  /> 
</form>
```

And the following js code

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = function() {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 116 : //F5 button
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            return false;

        case 82 : //R button
            if (event.ctrlKey) {
                event.returnValue = false;
                event.keyCode = 0;
                return false;
            }
    }
}

</script>
```

It kind of stops in Chrome seems like. However, in firefox on can still press <kbd>F5</kbd>!? What is the way to stop user from resubmitting a form / aka stop from refreshing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to overwrite the refresh button action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806231/is-there-a-way-to-overwrite-the-refresh-button-action)

Comment: What about the refresh button that is usually near the address bar? Or using the context menu?

Comment: And btw why would you like to do something like that? If you want to stop the user submitting a form, theres no client side code can do that, and even if you would disable it, you still have to validate it on server side to be sure its not the same form. Either way do this on server side.

Comment: Those we do not worry about

Comment: I want too because the intranet web solution we built can resubmit multiple times just by refreshing pages.. We want to stop resubmitting

Comment: No matter what you end up using in JavaScript, you will always have trouble until the server-side is fixed.

Comment: Yeep. As a developer, I explained this to manager and passed it along to client. I tried to figure out a perfect solution ; however, there was no quick fix solution found by me. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

It is a really bad idea to over-ride those functions. That's not something JavaScript can properly do. You need let the refresh happen, and use the `onbeforeunload` event:

See this duplicate question:

[Is there a way to overwrite the refresh button action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806231/is-there-a-way-to-overwrite-the-refresh-button-action)

And this one:

[Is there a way to capture/override Ctrl-R or F5 on IE using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400528/is-there-a-way-to-capture-override-ctrl-r-or-f5-on-ie-using-javascript)

**Use this to catch what you want:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     //de ... Do something else.
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to clear cache inside window.onunload?

Comment: Clear the browser cache? That is a security violation to attempt that from within a script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it work in chrome and Firefox that stop to refreshing the page

```
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {       
    if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {          
            return false;          
    }             
});
```

Comment: This would also prevent copy and paste... and work unreliably at that.

Comment: yes but you can right click on the boz and use copy pase . if we prevent the C and R the these letter would missed when user types.

Comment: try this login may be work the combination of two check like if(event.keyCode===82 && objEvent.ctrlKey ){ return false;}